# How to search and replace multiple lines with multiple lines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I looked at other answers regarding search and replace, but I just can't understand the patterns.

How can I change this part of a file (line numbers 153 ... 156)

```
        let view = string.utf8
        offset.pointee += string.substring(to: range.lowerBound).utf8.count
        length.pointee = Int32(view.distance(from:range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: view), to:range.upperBound.samePosition(in: view)))
        return token
```

and replace it with the lines below?

```
        let view:String.UTF8View = string.utf8

        if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: view),
           let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: view) {
            offset.pointee += Int32(string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound].utf8.count)
            length.pointee = Int32(view.distance(from: from, to: to))
            return token
        } else {
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: Are the numbers 153-156 part of the input file? Or did you just show them here for illustration?

Comment: was just showing them for illustration

Comment: Do you need to replace strictly lines 153..156, or the code that you show (which may or may not be on those lines)?

Comment: replace what's in 153-156 with the 2nd snippet of code, which will take up more than 3 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed $'153r replacementFile\n;153,156d' file
```

or for most seds:

```
sed -e '153r replacementFile' -e '153,156d' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed '153,156c\        let view:String.UTF8View = string.utf8\
    if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: view),\
       let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: view) {\
        offset.pointee += Int32(string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound].utf8.count)\
        length.pointee = Int32(view.distance(from: from, to: to))\
        return token\
    } else {\
        return nil\
    }' file
```

N.B. The first `\` preserves leading space and each line following except the last needs to be appended with `\`. The markdown in SO does not format properly when an empty line is represented by a single `\` (so I removed the second line of the replacement) but most shells should.

Comment: Hw do yo ou do this using variables instead of actual line numbers?

Comment: The last one works perfectly, but it only prints the perfect output to the screen, and doesn't replace the text within the document. Any hints on how to replace the text within the document?

Comment: OK, well I figured out a way that it would work, but it's an extra command.  I would still like to know if you can do it with what you've written.  (What I did was add '> newfile' then 'mv newfile file'

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is probably the best tool for this,

assuming your replacement text is in file replace.txt

```
$ sed '153,156{153{r replace.txt
                  }; d}' file
```

might be only working for GNU `sed`

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't GNU-sed for @karafka's answer and just want change lines at exact line-numbers, you could use the `ed` too.

```
ed -s file <<'EOF'
153,156c
        let view:String.UTF8View = string.utf8

        if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: view),
           let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: view) {
            offset.pointee += Int32(string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound].utf8.count)
            length.pointee = Int32(view.distance(from: from, to: to))
            return token
        } else {
            return nil
        }
.
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good case for the application of the [`Tie::File` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File), which maps an array to the lines of a text file so that any changes you make to the array will be reflected in the disk file. It's a core module, so you shouldn't need to install it.

Here, the `tie` call maps the array `@file` to your text file, and 
`splice` replaces the four lines of text with the replacement contents read from `DATA`.
Then `untie` updates and closes the file.

Note that you must alter `myfile.txt` to the real path to your input file.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

splice @file, 152, 4, <DATA>;

untie @file;



__DATA__
        let view:String.UTF8View = string.utf8

        if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: view),
           let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: view) {
            offset.pointee += Int32(string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound].utf8.count)
            length.pointee = Int32(view.distance(from: from, to: to))
            return token
        } else {
            return nil
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one-liner, to change lines `153..156` in `file` with contents of `repl.file`, in-place

```
perl -i -wpe'
    if   (153..155) { s/.*\n// }
    elsif ($.==156) { local $/; open $fh, "repl.file"; $_ = <$fh> };    
' file
```

(Or `$_ = path($file_name)->slurp` with [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm).)

This directly translates into a script, either by writing out a new file with changes and moving it over the original (see [in perlfaq5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?) and SO posts), or perhaps by [using `-i` (`$^I`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-Perl%27s--i-option-from-within-a-program?) within a script.

Comment: If it's a one-liner, why isn't it all on one line.

Comment: @user3439894 The term "one-liner" stands for something that is feasible to execute directly from the command line; it doesn't have to be presented in one long line, and it often isn't (for readability).  Also, modern shells allow multi-line input.  This was written and tested in one (long) line.

Comment: @user3439894 It is also a useful device to test a crude version of code. If it satisfies then one can write a proper script, with error checks, options, more elaborate processing etc. This is how it's intended here.